# Decorator: Using the Return Statement

Tags: python, function, decorator

For the hi() function, I have to use the return statement (return 'Hello World') for the code to work. Why can't I use the print function in this case? It gives me this error :AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'.

```
def smart(func):
    def inner():
        return func().upper()
    return inner

@smart
def hi():
    print('Hello World')

hi()
```

Comment: Because then `func()` would not be returning anything, so `func()` would evaluate to None, and `func().upper()` would be trying to call `upper()` on None.

Comment: I don't understand. I am using @smart() to call the decorator, so the hi() function should be connected to the smart(func)

Comment: What do you think `func().upper()` is doing?

Comment: It is taking a function and making that function return anything in uppercase

Comment: `func().upper()` is taking the **return value** of the original function (which you defined as `hi`) and putting it in upper case. That means the original `hi` must **return** a suitable value.

Comment: Why func().upper() can only take a return value instead of a printed value

Comment: See the [dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750136/3890632).