# Why do 'return bool' show different results in command prompt vs IDE

Tags: python, ide, interpreter

If I try the below code in command prompt , I get correct results, however, the same code using IDE(Atom) do not produce any results.

```
def search_for_vowels(word):
    """Display any vowels found in an asked for word"""
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    found = vowels.intersection(set(word))
    return bool(found)

search_for_vowels('galaxy')
```

Comment: What do you consider to be the *correct result*?

Comment: Most terminal will automatically display returned values, python scripts will not. Perhaps you meant `print(search_for_vowels('galaxy'))`?

Comment: @PM77-1 : I mean True or False

Comment: Where do you expect to see this result?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't produce results?  It doesn't _print_ anything, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @HenryEcker - Thanks, it works, but what exactly was wrong in my code. If you can bit elaborate, how can I call this function and get the return value printed at the same time.

Comment: @JohnGordon- Even for words with no vowel/s, it gives the same result: prints nothing

Comment: [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750136/15497888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command prompt to code is different than using IDE. When you use the command prompt you use something called `interpreter`, it will execute every line you write right after you click `enter`. You can write an object like that:

```
search_for_vowels('galaxy')
```

And it will print its `__repr__` to the screen.
In IDE it is not the case. It won't print you the `__repr__` of an object just be writing it. If you want to see the object or the function call result use `print` like that:

```
print(search_for_vowels('galaxy'))
```