# Python: Printing a function as a string inside of another printed string?

Tags: python

I am very new at python.  I am wondering of the easiest way or alternative to defining a function as a string, and then printing said string in another print line, such as demonstrated here:

```
def world():
    print("World!")

print("Hello " + world())
```

I am sure that this is an easy fix/search, but I cannot seem to find what I am searching for.  Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you mean like [`return 'World!'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750154/15497888) from  [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750136/15497888)

Comment: So, "defining a function as a string," doesn't make sense. Take a step back, and try to explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. But the answer you are looking for is,

```
def world():
    return ("World!")

print("Hello " + world())
```