# Return does not return information

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

When wanting to return a value with the return and wanting to use it later in a variable, nothing is returned to me.

```
#Actualizacion de informacion
def messageHandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    
    userName = update.effective_user['username']
    #text = update.message.text
    Usuario = userName
    ConsultarServer = ("Ingresa tu nombre de troncal correcta de lo contrario no se te regresara ninguna informacion.")

    if ConsultarSaldoSw2 in update.message.text:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Ingresa tu nombre de troncal correcta de lo contrario no se te regresara ninguna informacion.")
        text2 = update.message.text
        return text2
    
   
    print (text2)
    
    if text2 in update.message.text:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Ingresa el servidor sw o sw2")
        text3 = update.message.text
        return text3
    
    
    
    print (text3)
```

Comment: `return` ends the function. Since you return after setting `text2`, the rest of the code will never be executed.

Comment: You do not have return under all circumstances, but only within two if loops. If none of both conditions is fulfilled, you have no active return statement in your function. So I expect you get a None in that case

Comment: And if the first `if` condition fails, you don't set `text2`, and the rest of the function will get an error because it tries to use an undefined variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Comment: "nothing is returned" isn't possible. Something will be returned (it may be `None`). So how do you call this function and what do you get back?

Comment: could you give me examples please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is exhausted, and it doesn't meet any of your conditions, it will `return None` by default. Consider this shortened example:

```
def messageHandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):

    if ConsultarSaldoSw2 in update.message.text:
        return text2
    
    if text2 in update.message.text:
        return text3
    
    # None of these if conditions are met, so nothing is returned
```

If you don't enter any of these `if` statements, you never return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Return ends the function and does not print anything to the console. Also seems that they're endpoints for conditionals that may not be met.