# How do i call a function within a class in python

Tags: python

i am having issues with my code. i have a python class and functions it. i want to be able to call the function inside it to another function, below is my code

```
import random

class now:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def num1(self):
        print('One')

    def num2(self):
        print('Two')

    def num3(self):
        print('Three')

    def all(self):
        num = [self.num1, self.num2, self.num3]
        random.choice(num)()

    def start(self):
        print('my name is: ', self.name)
        print('i choose:', self.all() )


my_take = now('king')

my_take.start()
```

my problem now is that when i run the code, on the i choose, self.all() is given me none

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Answer (score 2):

Your `all` method has no `return` statement in it, so it implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: When i add return to it, i get an error of <bound method now.all of <__main__.now object at 0x0000029EBC8C1C88>>

Comment: Don't delete the empty brackets after random.choice. It should be `return random.choice(num)()`

Comment: Thank you, i used a return on all of them and then added return to the random.choice as you said and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the Strings, not print them. Try it like this:

```
import random

class now: 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def num1(self):
        return 'One'
    
    def num2(self):
        return 'Two'
    
    def num3(self):
        return 'Three'
    
    def all(self):
        num = [self.num1, self.num2, self.num3]
        return random.choice(num)()
    
    def start(self):
        print('my name is: ', self.name)
        print('i choose:', self.all() )
```

You are using a lot of Methods to accomplish a very simple tast. Why dont try it like this:

```
import random

class now: 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def start(self):
        print('my name is: ', self.name)
        print('i choose:', random.choice(["One", "Two", "Three"]) )
```

Comment: Even at that, it still shows None

Comment: If I run exactly this code I don't get None but a number. @chibuike ogodo. It outputs following: ```my name is:  king
i choose: One```

Comment: on you second answer, that's not what i want. thou i just used this simple terms on it. i wanted to create different functions with different behavior and have them randomly selected. but then i needed to use the simple term to illustrate. But i have been able to do it. thank for your help

Comment: you are getting None because nothing is actually running, it is only interpreting the code. To run it, initialize the class with a name then call .start()