# The text file created does not shows each string as None, how can I fix it?

Tags: python

```
while("list\n" in animals) :
    animals.remove("list\n")

def getAnimal(animals):
    x = random.randint(1,len(animals))
    while True:
        y = random.randint(1,len(animals))
        if y != x:
            break
    if animals[x].split()[-1] == animals[y].split()[-1]:
        print(animals[x].split()[-1])
    else:
        print(animals[x][:-1], animals[y][:-1])

df = open('genAnimals.txt','w')
for i in range(10):
    df.write(str(getAnimal(animals)))
df.close()
```

The text file created does not shows each string as None, how can I fix it? The text file shows NoneNoneNone...

Comment: Where is `animals` assigned? What is your expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Comment: "Does not shows each string as None"? Assuming *animals* is a list (not shown in the question) then your output file will contain NoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNone

Comment: When you call df.write( str(getAnimal(animals))) the str function gets the string of the returning object of the getAnimal, which is None in your case because this function doesn't return anything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.