# How can i save return as a variable with full range python

Tags: python, function, variables, return, range

```
#first 
def table_(x):
    num=range(11)
    digit=int(input('Table of='))

    for num in range(11):
       # return(digit,'x',num,'=',num*digit)
        print(digit,'x',num,'=',num*digit)


num2=table_(2)
num2
```

Comment: What "return"? What are you wanting to return from the function? Unrelated, why do you take `x` as input to the function and never use it? Please explain what you are trying to do since we can't figure that out by backwards engineering broken code.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. The assignment `num = range(11)` is irrelevant, because `num` is overwritten each time the loop iterates. What value should `num2` ultimately have?

Comment: I suspect some confusion over the difference between `return` and `print`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it, perhaps.

Comment: Your return value is `None` because your function doesnt explicitly return something so it will implicitly return `None`

Answer (score 0):

To print the multiplication table from 0 to 11 for example, you can modify your function like this:

```
def mul_table(digit):
    table = ''
    for num in range(12):
        table += f'{digit:2d} x {num:2d} = {num*digit:2d}\n'
    return table
```

Test with table of 2:

```
table2 = mul_table(2)
print(table2)
 2 x  0 =  0
 2 x  1 =  2
 2 x  2 =  4
 2 x  3 =  6
 2 x  4 =  8
 2 x  5 = 10
 2 x  6 = 12
 2 x  7 = 14
 2 x  8 = 16
 2 x  9 = 18
 2 x 10 = 20
 2 x 11 = 22
```

Comment: @masroor_rajput, is that what you want?

Comment: i want to save this table as a variable?

Comment: i am newbe i have just started learning programing

Comment: @masroor_rajput - see my update, now `table2 ` is the variable name containing multiplication table of 2.

Comment: @masroor_rajput *what* do you want, exactly? Some advice, you want to at least tell us the *type* of the object and it's value. The "table" isn't anything, that is simply what you printed to the screen.