Subprocess with .Popen returning empty stdout
I'm trying to write a code that allows me to terminate a calculation that is potentially stuck and doesn't respond to keyboardinterrupt. I solved it with subprocesses. However, the code does not return a value if it's not stuck and ends successfully in time.
I have this code in file "temp2.py"
import os
import signal
import time


# condition for aborting subprocess2
def subprocess1(timeout, subprocess2_pid):
    # timer for max duration of the calculation
    time.sleep(timeout)
    
    # send termination signal to subprocess2
    os.kill(subprocess2_pid, signal.SIGTERM)


# contains potentially problematic calculation that can not be aborted with keyboardinterrupt
def subprocess2():
    # in this case the calculation finishes immediately
    # to simulate a case where the calculation is "stuck", try calculating 999**99999999
    result = 999**9999
    return result

And I have this code in file "temp.py"
import subprocess
from temp2 import subprocess1, subprocess2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Start subprocess 2 (calculation)
    process2 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", "from temp2 import subprocess2; subprocess2()"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Get the PID of subprocess 2
    subprocess2_pid = process2.pid

    # Start subprocess 1 (timer/condition)
    timeout = 2  # Set timeout for subprocess 1
    process1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", f"from temp2 import subprocess1; subprocess1({timeout}, {subprocess2_pid})"])
    
    # Get stdout and stderr and wait for subprocess2 to finish, so that consecutive calculations are delayed
    stdout, stderr = process2.communicate()

I do not get a result for my 999**9999 calculation. stdout and stderr are both empty variables. I also considered using alternatives like .run, .call, or .check_output instead of .Popen, but to my knowledge, only the latter is able to generate the pid I need to terminate subprocess2 if necessary.
Why is stdout empty?
Specs: Python 3.11.4 // Windows 11 // Spyder 5.4.3

Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.

@itprorh66 Thank you for the link and your reply. I honestly thought my question was straight forward, but apperently I was mistaken. I don't expect anyone to just give me the entire code, but I do appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction. For example, with my question "I was wondering if there are any solutions to this problem by now." I was hoping someone would write a one-liner like "It's still not possible." (which would be an update to similar 9+ year old posts, and something could have changed by now) or provide a link to a website that deals with the question in more depth.

@itprorh66 And regarding the specific question/idea in the last paragraph, I hoped someone would give me feedback in the form of "Yeah, that's a possibility, you can try that." or something like "Actually, there is a much simpler solution than doing it with subprocesses, namely ...." But if that's the wrong way to pose a question, then let me try and edit the post accordingly.

Why are you expecting output? You never use print() anywhere in the code. Change return result to print(result) and you should get something.

Or print(subprocess2())' in your subprocess.Popen() call.

@Barmar Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion and it worked in this case. I didn't know you have to print the output first in order to use it in the main file. However, when result is very long (for instance a numpy array like this: result = -1*np.ones(4000, dtype=np.int64)), the print output gives me literally this: [-1 -1 -1 ... -1 -1 -1], only containing a fraction of the original data. But my main program would take this exact print output and use it in temp.py for stdout, which is not what I want. I want to use the original array of size 4000 (in this exemplary case).

Okay, i solved it by including this command: np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf). If anyone else has a better idea, I would love to know it.

Of course you have to print it. Unless you're in an interactive REPL, nothing gets printed automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it
